# how to download file from public s3 bucket using console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download the file from a public S3 bucket using AWS console. When I put the below in the browser but getting an error. Wanted to visually see what else is there in that folder and explore

Public S3 bucket :
s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce.samples/flightdata/input

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to access an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to a different AWS account. This *cannot* be done via the Amazon S3 management console.

Instead, I recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You can use:

```
aws s3 ls s3://flightdata/input/
```

That will show you the objects stored in that bucket/path.

You could then download the objects with:

```
aws s3 sync s3://flightdata/input/ input
```